# Audio upload to GridFS in a NextJS app not working

Tags: next.js, gridfs, next.js13, web-mediarecorder, gridfs-stream

I am working on a NextJS test app, called njs-voice-rcd, where I want to upload some voice recording made by the user to a mongo DB using GridFS. At this point I have the voice recording part already working as expected. But I can't figure out the correct way to upload the audio blob that I have to GridFS. Any relevant tip would by highly appreciated.

This is how I started making the app:

```
% npx create-next-app@latest
...
% cd njs-voice-rcd
% npm i mongoose gridfs-stream
```

Beside the above, below is the relevant part of the code for my question:

First, this is the function (stopRecording) executed when I stop the recording process:

```
const mrRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
.....

const stopRecording = () => {
    setRecordingStatus("inactive");

    if (!mrRef.current) return

    mrRef.current?.stop();
    mrRef.current.onstop = () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current,
                                   {type: mimeType});
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        setAudio(audioUrl);
        loadToMongoDB(audioBlob);
    };
}; /* End of stopRecording */
```

As one can see a function called *loadToMongoDB* is called to do the work related to my question.

Hereafter is the code of *loadToMongoDB*. But it does not work the way it is now. Please let me know if you see something wrong.

```
async function loadToMongoDB(blob:Blob) {
    const mongoURI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MDB_URI_AUDIO!;
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
        console.log('We have a connection!')
        // Work to do once we have a connection.
        .....
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
    }
} /* End of loadToMongoDB */
```

For the line of code:

```
await mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
```

This is the error I get in the web console:

```
Error connecting to MongoDB: TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default().connect is not a function
```

Here is what I have in the package.json file:

```
"gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
"mongoose": "^7.4.2",
```

I have also tried some variations for the code inside *loadToMongoDB*, but nothing is working.

I can provide more detail if necessary. Let me know if this is needed and what I should provide.